# Get users current position the best way

Tags: php, mysql, query-optimization

I am making a ranking app and are getting the users position in the ranking this way:

```
$sql = "SELECT fk_player_id FROM ".$prefix."_publicpoints
            WHERE date BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-12-31'
                GROUP BY fk_player_id
            HAVING SUM(points) > 235";
```

This is working as is should but are having one downfall. The query can get quite heavy if I have a ranking with 500.000 users. Then it have to run through all the users which have higher points than 235. Lets say that 235 give a posistion as # 345.879. Thats alot of rows... How can I do this in a better way? Atleast when I call the db?

Hoping 4 help and thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1):

3 possible solutions that may (or may or may not combine them together depending on the situation

- Add indices to the ranking columns
- pre-compute the ranks only when it changes
- pre-compute the ranks with a cron job - it should not matter if it is 10 minutes late.

If it is a generic ranking page, you can pre-render the page either with a template engine and cache  it

you may be able to optimize your mysql performance as well either with more ram or configuring the caching of queries & temp tables